# Post to an endpoint not in the same module in unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails 2 legacy project. I have `MyController` in `Foo` module:

```
module Api::Foo
  class MyController < ::ActionController::Base
    def doJob
      puts "do the job"
    end
  end
end
```

In routes.rb I have:

```
map.connect 'api/foo/dojob', :controller => 'api/foo/my',:action => 'doJob', :conditions => { :method => :post }
```

I have another controller, which is outside the `Foo` module, it is in `Bar` module:

```
module Api::Bar
  class AnotherController < ::ActionController::Base
    def doCalculation
          puts "do the calculation"
    end
  end
end
```

In unit test of `AnotherControllerTest`, how can I post to endpoint `api/foo/dojob` ?

```
class Api::Bar::AnotherControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   def setup
   end

   test 'test internal api call' do
     # how to post to "api/foo/dojob"??
   end
end
```

I tried `post "/api/foo/dojob",{}`, it doesn't work.

Comment: why would you do that ?. Controllers should not be calling other controllers' code. If you need code from one controller in another one, then extract it into a `module` or `class`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `ActionController::TestCase` abstracts out the whole step of actually performing a actual HTTP request.

What `ActionController::TestCase` does when you do `get :foo` is create an instance of `Api::Bar::AnotherController` and pass it a mocked request. It then calls the `#foo` method on the controller. All this seemed like a great idea at the time since it lets you poke around in the controllers internals and was a bit faster.

It derives the class from the name of the test case class.  While you could possibly override this to instantiate some other controller its the wrong answer to the wrong problem. The whole idea of a unit test is that it tests one component in isolation.

To do integration testing where you test multiple controllers you want [ActionController::IntegrationTest](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/testing.html#integration-testing). An integration test actually sends a HTTP request to a test server. This is also a more future [proof testing strategy](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html) since controller tests have been axed.

```
require 'test_helper'
class ApiFlowsTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
   def setup
   end

   test 'test internal api call' do
     post "api/foo/dojob", { foo: 'bar' }
     get  "api/foo/bar"
     assert_response :success
   end
end
```

Comment: On a side note - the whole idea of unit testing controllers was deeply flawed and has very much fallen out of vogue in the rails world.